# Implementing SSO between 3 websites

Tags: c#

I am sorry if this question has already been asked, I couldn`t find it.

My organization has two websites:

1. www.abc.com
2. www.abc.online-rewards.com

User starts by logging in to www.abc.com and for going to the other website (www.abc.online-rewards.com), the user has to log in again. I want to eliminate this issue by creating a dashboard (dashboard will display employees info and his rewards, so that they can be redeemed through second website).

Can anybody help me with this issue. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Cross domain SSO is difficult to implement. You may take a look at the way SO does it over the StackExchange network: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work/64274#64274